# Comments on iOS app sorted from newest to oldest

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, sorting

I was reading the comment as usual, then there is a new comment. The app reloaded, and huh, it sorted the comments reversely.

[image]

- App Version: 1.4.2.2
- Device: iPad 2 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.2 (Build 13F69)

Comment: You're using oooooooooooold version. Time to update. In the very least, update before posting bug report as most chances are the bug is already fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh, I thought that it would auto update?

Comment: No, what I remember is that when it identifies new version it only asks you to update, but not forcing it. You can start a feature request asking to have the app auto update itself automatically.

Comment: Also, maybe it's not the app fault, but [your settings](http://www.howtogeek.com/232426/how-to-enable-or-disable-automatic-updates-for-ios-apps/).

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, I have that feature on. I also remember that it used to announce me to update the app. Now it hasn't told me that for a long time

Comment: I have started the request http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280344/260800