# Have a manual update button on the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

As you can see below, my app hasn't been updated for a long time. It used to pop up a notification telling me to update the app, now it doesn't. This leads me to some failed bug reports today.

What has happened? I think that for whatever reason, you should have an update button so that I can manual update it.

[image]

- App Version: 1.4.2.2
- Device: iPad 2 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.2 (Build 13F69)

Comment: oh, you're using the Beta channel. Try removing it and install the app from Apple Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I pushed 1.4.2.2, I included a banner above the link telling people about Test Flight, but I hedged by still including a link to the updated app in case Test Flight didn't work out.  It looks like we have a few people downloaded the beta app and kept using it.

I've gone ahead and removed the link to download and bumped the version so the app will direct you to the page and then keep bugging you until you stop using it.

Comment: i want to stop using this buggy app :((

Comment: @Ooker you should have received an email from Apple to join the program and install 1.5.3.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is necessary to have a manual update button. If you are part of the beta program, you should have had an <strike>invitation to join</strike> TestFlight, Apples new mechanism to allow users to test apps and to deploy test releases. (Oh no, there was a meta post: [Stack Exchange iOS app beta moving to Test Flight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270528/245360))

Using TestFlight, you will receive an email, a push notification and a badge to tell you there is an update. That is enough to me :)

Comment: Am I that out of date? 

Comment: About half a year or so :) @Ooker

Comment: Huh, I also wasn't really aware of that, but since I have only android device for year+ it doesn't really matter to me. :)

Comment: Lol. Enjoy your app for Android @Sha. You should be more active on meta, else you would have known this.

Comment: But I don't. It feels utterly inferior to the iOS app, and with every bug fix and new feature that Brian is adding it only get worse. :D

Comment: Then get an iOS device next time @Sha

Comment: Not my call... got it from work. :/

Comment: Get a new job @Sha. Maybe there is a spot on Brian's team. Then you definitely will get an iOS device.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I remembered that you once wished to have an iPad as a Christmas gift...

Comment: @Pat LOL, good one! ;)

Comment: @Ooker really?? I'm almost certain you mistake me for someone else as I never really had, or wanted, an iPad - but feel free to find the reference and refresh my memory! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard almost correct =))). Sorry for mistaken you https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shadow+wizard%22+%22ipad%22+stack+exchange+christmas&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b

Comment: Close enough @Ook